# I can't decrease my ASP controls' height as low as I want when using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

there seem to be a minimal grid row height when I use bootstrap.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GV_ExpositionsDoc" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableModelValidation="True"  ShowHeader="false" OnRowDataBound="GV_Expositions_RowDataBound"  CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" >
      <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
              <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False" Font-Size="XX-Small"  />
              <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="text-align:right" Font-Size="XX-Small" />
              <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label_Nom" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' Width="350" Height="20"/>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When I change my Label height from 20 to 50, it does seem to work (more or less twice bigger).
But when I try to lower it to 10, it sticks to the same height.
Is there a minimum Height set by Bootstrap? Is there a way to override this?

I tried to set it into the    section but it did not make it either.

Comment: It seems to come from:
CssClass="table table-hover table-striped"
If I remove it, my row heith renders at 10 pixels as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To override another css statement use !important before the semicolon in the css, example:

```
div {
 height: 100% !important;
}
```